# mongrel_rails start command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my server I am unable to run mongrel_rails start.  I looked in /usr/bin/ and could not locate the mongrel_rails file.  Instead I found it in /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin.  The file includes #!/usr/bin/ruby1.8, but I am still not getting this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a symlink:

```
ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/mongrel_rails /usr/bin/mongrel_rails
```

Or even better, add `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin` to your `PATH`.